# Replace multiple periods in string with just one period

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'm trying to replace any group of two or more periods with just a single period.
I suspect the + operator is involved, but I've had nothing but sorrow trying to make the expression using that...
So I thought as an experiment I would try to replace just 3 periods with one period.
The nonsense below is what I came up with, and of course it doesn't work.

```
OutNameNoExt:= RegExReplace(OutNameNoExt,"\.\.\." , ".")
```

Or even better, can I alter this existing expression

OutNameNoExt:= RegExReplace(OutNameNoExt,"[^a-zA-Z0=9_-]" , ".")

so that it never produces more than one period in a row?

Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
OutNameNoExt:= RegExReplace(OutNameNoExt,"\.{2,}" , ".")
```

Or, if the `{n,m}` (i.e., at least `n`, but no more than `m` times) syntax is not allowed, you can use the following instead:

```
OutNameNoExt:= RegExReplace(OutNameNoExt,"\.\.+" , ".")
```

Alternatively, you can also change the existing expression to the following so that it doesn't produce more than one period in a row:

```
OutNameNoExt:= RegExReplace(OutNameNoExt,"[^a-zA-Z0=9_-]+" , ".")
```

Comment: Thanks sir! It works. Now I'll go refresh myself on what those curly braces mean.

Comment: @user1544566: You're welcome. `X{n,m}` basically means *match X, at least n but not more than m times*. When you omit the value of `m`, it means the expression is unbounded. For example, `\.{2,}` means *match . at least 2 times*. Here's a link that explains regex basic constructs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Answer (score 2):

For Java, the following regex is working to replace multiple dots with single dot:

```
String str = "-.-..-...-.-.--..-k....k...k..k.k-.-";
str.replaceAll("\\.\\.+", ".")
```

Output:

```
-.-.-.-.-.--.-k.k.k.k.k-.-
```

Comment: Works perfect for me